# how to set a specific position though command line?

Tags: java, cmd, position

```
String cmd = "start calc.exe";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(codeString);
```

I can call calculator out, but I wish to specify a accurate position like (200,300).

how can I rewrite my cmd String?

I know that `java.awt.window` can set a window or frame to the specific position.
Is there any method I can use to fill frame or window with my process?

Comment: Nope, you'll need to access native code to achieve that.

Comment: The command you are using is Windows specific, you need to research the options Windows provides you to determine what it allows you to do.  Java doesn't allow you to change the way windows works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clean pure java solution because JDK does not provide API that can control non-java windows. So, if you want to can use JNI/JNA.

But I can suggest you a patch that will typically work.

Windows OS allows moving windows using keyboard. Try the following manually:

Win+R 
type calc and press enter 
press alt+space
press M
press enter

now use arrows to move the window. Press ESC to exit this mode.

All these actions can be implemented using `java.awt.Robot`. 
So, you can run calculator and then immediately move its window where you want.

Well, this is not clear solution, but very simple one.

Expected Problems:

1. Alt+space is mapped to other, custom application
2. Other window that started together with calc overlaps it.
3. User will see that window is created somewhere and then quickly moved.

So, everything depends on how important all this for you. This solution is good as an exercise or demo but bad for real commercial application.

Comment: wow,that is quite a good idea.thx for your reply.i can give a try.before i met this Robot class,but i didn't notice this method.

Comment: Good luck with this. But keep in mind the mentioned limitations.